# Locally asymptotic stable equilibrium of a non-linear difference equations system

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Theorem 4.8 in the book "[discrete dynamical system](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-36776-4)" gives a sufficient condition for an equilibrium to be locally stable in a nonlinear difference system.

It basically says the following: a nonlinear difference system given by $x_{t+1}=\phi(x_t)$ with equilibrium $x^*$ is locally stable if

1. the absolute value of all eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix $D\phi(x^*)$ is strictly less than $1$
2. $\phi$ is a $C^1$ differeomorphism on $R^n$.

The second condition here is both strong and restrictive. Intuitively, since we only care about local stability, should it suffice to just require $\phi$ be a $C^1$ differeomorphism on a neighborhood of the equilibrium? Could any one confirm this intuition, and if possible, give a reference?

Besides, does $\phi$ being locally $C^1$ differeomorphism together with absolute value of one eigenvalue of the Jacobian is strictly bigger than $1$ guarantee that the equilibrium being locally unstable? (assume the equilibrium is a hyperbolic fixed point)